# Suitable control to specify a filter parameter with a main category and its subcategories

Tags: filter, discovery

I'm designing a list view to show workflows. The worklflows can be divided into two main categories, workflows that are ongoing and workflows that will not have any more processes. 
These categories are so far called:

- Ongoing
- Finished

Note that possible alternatives to these terms are welcome as well. 
In the Ongoing category there are as of now two sub categories:

- Active
- Suspended

In the Finished category there are five sub categories:

- Completed
- Cancelled
- Aborted
- Expired
- Error

Now I need integrate these conditions into a filter panel. I've developed a mockup but I'm not very comfortable with how it turned out.

[image]

I feel that discoverability is being compromised since states are hidden. Not to mention the bad after taste of having Cancelled workflows sorted under the category Finished. However better terms has not been found so far.

I would like to know if there is an established interactive control to use that could achieve this in a filter panel that is more transparent and offer better discoverability than the one I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that showing more info is beneficial, so I would put it all out there. The checkboxes would be visible but disabled unless the associated radio button is on to activate the row.  You'd want better spacing/grouping than I've done here to reinforce the relationship between the various buttons.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f713R1.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: A pretty neat idea. This could have worked. However I've switched jobs since posting this question, so I'm I wont be able to proceed with your approach. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't notice the date.  Thanks for the check mark!

Answer (score 0):

In our app we use a nested pick list type filter. This could become unwieldy in some circumstances, but in your case you only have two main categories, it should be fine.

[image: nested picklist]

Comment: Totally offtopic but how did you create this recorded gif?

Comment: screen record via Camtasia, publish to gif file. Super useful for stuff like this.